# Using Ruby hash key as parameters

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use a parameter as my key to find the value in a hash, and I just confused about why I couldn't get the value by the first way. I am new to Ruby.

```
def getCards(player,hash)
    a =$player
    puts "a = "+a.to_s
    puts "a.class = "+a.class.to_s

    puts " hash[:a]"+" #{hash[:a]}"
    puts " hash[:'1']"+" #{hash[:"1"]}"

 end
```

edit:

```
 def getCards(player,hash)
   puts player 
  #result successfully 1 or any number that I gets from console

   puts hash[player]
   # nothing but 1 is actually a key in my hash 

# {1=>["yellow3", "yellow8", "green9", "black11", "red1", "black7", "red5", #"yellow7",  more results ..

 end
```

Comment: hash["1"] returns a result that I need , however why I can not use a variable as a parameter key to get the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Ruby is not PHP or Perl, so that should be `player` and not `$player`. Argument names and their corresponding use as variables are identical.

`$player` refers to the *global variable* of that name, which is unrelated and will be presumed to be undefined unless otherwise set.

Now if by `hash[:a]` you mean to access the contents of the hash under the key with the player value you've assigned to `a` then what you actually want is:

```
hash[player]
```

Where that represents looking up an entry with that key. `a` is a variable in this case, `:a` is the *symbol* "a" which is just a constant, like a label, which has no relation to the variable.

Don't forget that `"#{x}"` is equivalent to `x.to_s` so just use interpolation instead of this awkward `"..." + x.to_s` concatenation.

Another thing to keep in mind is that in Ruby case has significant meaning. Variable and method names should follow the `get_cards` style. Classes are `ClassName` and constants are like `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why I can not assign a =$player?

Comment: You can do that, but it doesn't mean anything here since `$player` is `nil` and completely unrelated to the `player` argument. Just because it's valid Ruby code doesn't mean it works as you expect.

Comment: def getCards(player,hash) 
   puts player // result 1
  
   puts hash[player]
 result nil
 
 end

Comment: I gave player = 1 , and puts 1 successfully ,buy why hash[player]
 returns nil? and player.class = string

Comment: It's really unclear what input data you're using, so you may need to open a new question with additional information. Remember, `1` the integer and `"1"` the string are not in any way equivalent in Ruby, they are different hash keys. You can use *any object* as a key in a Ruby hash, and although symbols like `:name` are the most common, they are by no means required.

Comment: Thanks  tadman , I solved the problem by changed the type of my key ,I used int as my key and it works fine by  puts hash[players.to_i]  and player is a parameter that was sent previously .